# I am trying to make a bunch of inline html cards with divs. For some reason the second card is getting pushed down when I add any block elements

Tags: html, css

This is the code before I add a p tag to the second card, once I add a p tag the second card gets moved down(as show in the image below.) The second card is contained in a inline block, does adding the p tag effect the display styling of the container.

```css
body {
    background-color: #999999;
}
.ml-1 {
 margin-left: 1rem;
}

.mw {
    width: 100%;
}



.card1-container {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.card1 {
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #24242475;
    opacity: .8;
    height: 20rem;
    margin: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    border: .3rem solid black;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card1-header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF90;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.card1-header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.75rem;
}

.card1 p {
    text-align: center;
}


.card2-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: grey;
    border: dotted black;

}
```

```html
<!-- Simple Namecard -->
<div>
    <div class="card1-container">
        <div class="card1"> 
            <div class="card1-header">
                <h1 class="ml-1"> Name: </h1>
                <h2 class="mw"> Eric </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card2-container">   
        <div class="card2"> 
            <div class="card2-header">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, what version?

Comment: No I am not using bootstrap. Im trying to stay away from frameworks.

Comment: Add your code causing the issue in the snippet included.

Comment: Why not give all the cards the same class names?

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent div a class name and use `flex`. Then use `align-items: center;` to align them.

```css
body {
    background-color: #999999;
}
.ml-1 {
 margin-left: 1rem;
}

.mw {
    width: 100%;
}



.card1-container {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.card1 {
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #24242475;
    opacity: .8;
    height: 20rem;
    margin: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    border: .3rem solid black;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card1-header {
    background-color: #FFFFFF90;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.card1-header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.75rem;
}

.card1 p {
    text-align: center;
}


.card2-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: grey;
    border: dotted black;

}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Simple Namecard -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card1-container">
        <div class="card1"> 
            <div class="card1-header">
                <h1 class="ml-1"> Name: </h1>
                <h2 class="mw"> Eric </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card2-container">   
        <div class="card2"> 
            <div class="card2-header">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```